# orderBy with react-firebase-hooks/firestore not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `react-firebase-hooks/firestore`

and I have:

```
  const [documents, documentsLoading, documentsError]: [DocumentInterface[], boolean, Error] = useCollectionDataOnce(
    firebase.firestore().collection('documents')
      .where('userId', '==', firebase.auth()?.currentUser?.uid || null)
      .orderBy('updatedAt')
    ,
    { idField: 'id' }
  )
```

which returns no results. If I remove the `.orderBy('updatedAt')`, then I have results. Why would that be?

Comment: Does the error in the console state that you have to create an index?

Comment: Ahhhh - there is it. Thanks!

Comment: But that seems strange that I need a composite index for a where and an orderBy, no?

Comment: Yes it does, I've never used react-firebase-hooks before so I'm not sure if they do any magic to the firestore reference you pass in. What does the composite index ask you to do? That might be an indicator of what's happening.

Comment: For instance, what does that idField variable do? Once you call this useCollectionDataOnce query, does it add a .where(idField, '==', id)? If so, that'd be why it needs a separate index. If the composite index shows that is the case, I'll make an answer to the question that you can accept!

Comment: That's it - please make an answer

Comment: I'm actually not sure if it's creating a second where clause. I checked the source code and it doesn't seem to do that. Regardless, I created a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query requires a composite index. If you check the console, the error will include a link that will automatically create it for you.